# Any way to write this shorter/dryer?

Tags: javascript, dry

Just wondering if there's anyway I could write this loop shorter.

```
var m, d, y

// date.length === format.length
for (var i = 0, len = format.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (/m/.test(format[i])) m = date[i]
  if (/d/.test(format[i])) d = date[i]
  if (/y/.test(format[i])) y = date[i]
}
```

Comment: If you try to explain what you want to achieve, it would be easier to give you a solution.

Comment: This code could really do whatever, it just assigns `m`,`d` or `y` to `date[i]` if the string in position `format[i]` matches `"m"`, `"d"` or `"y"` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is short enough so that I wouldn't change it, but for the sake of an example, you could make your code more dynamic like this:

```
var obj = {};
var mdy = ['m', 'd', 'y']
var curLetter;
for (var i = 0, len = format.length; i < len; i++) {
    curLetter = mdy[i];
    if ((new Regexp(curLetter)).test(format[i])) obj[curLetter] = date[i];
}
var m = obj.m;
var d = obj.d;
var y = obj.y;
```

The last three rows you don't need, if you'd just just the properties of obj.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax saving ?
Save a var; put it in the for header

```
// date.length === format.length
for (var m, d, y, i = 0, len = format.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (/m/.test(format[i])) m = date[i]
  if (/d/.test(format[i])) d = date[i]
  if (/y/.test(format[i])) y = date[i]
}
```

Or maybe conditionals:

```
for (var m, d, y, i = 0, len = format.length; i < len; i++) {
  (/m/.test(format[i])) ? m = date[i] 
  :(/d/.test(format[i])) ? d = date[i] 
  :(/y/.test(format[i])) y = date[i] 
  : continue;
}
```

But this changes the logic and im not sure this is wanted

Maybe you could add a continue for faster execution but again not sure about the logic

```
for (var m, d, y, i = 0, len = format.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (/m/.test(format[i])){
    m = date[i]
    //jump to next since this has been found
    continue;
  }
  if (/d/.test(format[i])){
    d = date[i]
    continue;
  }
  if (/y/.test(format[i])){
    y = date[i]
    continue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `eval()` to write a more generic loop.

```
var parts = ['d', 'm', 'y'],
    part,
    indexOfPart,
    d, m, y;

// Iterate over the variable you want to assign
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    part = parts[i];

    // Find out where in the format is the current part of the date
    indexOfPart = format.indexOf(part);

    // If it is present, use eval to assign your variable
    if (indexOfPart !== -1) {
        eval(part + " = date[" + indexOfPart + "];");
    }
}
```